# MySQL, сравнить 2 json

Tags: mysql, json

Таблица

```
------------------------------------------
id | user_id |    begin_date      | p_ids
------------------------------------------
35 |       1 |2019-04-02 12:00:00 | [2,3]
38 |       1 |2019-04-02 15:00:00 | [2]



SELECT * FROM `orders`  
WHERE user_id = 1  
AND begin_date = "2019-04-02 12:00:00"
AND json_contains(p_ids, '[2,3]');
```

Пытаюсь вот сравнить 2 json-а. json_contains смотрит лишь есть ли данные в столбце, не проверяет на полное соответствие. Что можно тут придумать?

Comment: *A candidate array is contained in a target array if and only if every element in the candidate is contained in some element of the target.* Покажите дополнительно то же примером данных (несколько записей, без соответствия, с полным соответствием, и с частичным соответствием).

Comment: Если имеется в виду, что `p_ids` есть строго `[2,3]`, а не, скажем, `[1,2,3]`, то `AND json_contains(p_ids, '[2,3]') AND json_contains('[2,3]', p_ids)`.

Comment: @Akina кажись работает. Никаких issues не будет?

Comment: @Akina Спасибо большое! Напишите в ответ, поставлю как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция json_contains(), когда её аргументы - массивы, просто проверяет, что каждый элемент второго массива присутствует в составе первого массива. При этом не обращается внимание ни на порядок, ни на дубликаты, ни на "излишки".

Если надо проверить на равенство, то следует использовать

```
AND json_contains(p_ids, '[2,3]') 
AND json_contains('[2,3]', p_ids)
```

А вот если в массиве могут быть дубликаты, и надо проверить на строгое соответствие (например, предыдущий код даст True для аргументов `[2,2,3]` и `[2,3,3]`), то задача становится слегка нетривиальной...

Comment: Спасибо за такое хорошее объяснение!